# Logic Apps - Copy Blob File to Server On-Premises

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

We're trying to copy a blob file to an on-premises server. We have attachments being saved as blobs; we'd like to copy the file without the use of FTP which requires certs.

I was thinking we may need to use a trigger to fire off a function app which would do the "move file", would this be right or is there anything I have missed? I've not found anything online which helps with this :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can (or already have) use the Azure On-Premises Data Gateway https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install then you can use the File System connector to put the files on a file share on the on-premises server.

Comment: Hi, can this be used to copy a file (pdf) from blob to on-prem server, and does this work on trigger rather than a set time? This looks like data fro on-prem to cloud?

Comment: You would trigger the logic app with the 'When a blob is added or modified' blob storage trigger, then use the File System connector to write to the on-prem server.  The on-premise data gateway allow Logic Apps to gain access to on-premise resources.